# Get event click in tableviewrow titanium

Tags: titanium, tableview

I have customized a tableviewrow in tableview with image and several buttons. I have gotten the index of the row that I clicked, but I need to make it so that when I click a button in tableviewrow, it will return the index of the row.
I also want to test to see whether or not I have clicked rows.
How should I do this?

Answer (score 5):

[click](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableView-event-click) event of table gives you the rowData of the row clicked. So, you can access all the data which is assigned with that row. Example code:

```
var data = [];
for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    var row = Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow({
        id: i,
        title : 'some title'+i,
    });

    data.push(row);
}
table = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
    data : data
});
table.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    alert(e.rowData.id+":"+e.rowData.title);
});
```